# cordova misreporting screen.width and screen.height

Tags: javascript, cordova, screen, samsung-mobile

I have this code in the beginning of my cordova android app

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);    
function onDeviceReady() {    
   alert("screen width is " + screen.width + " screen height is " + screen.height);
}
```

but it is not working as intended:

Galaxy Note 3 is total garbage: (should report 1920×1080)
[image]

Hisense HS-U980 works fine (should report 1280x720)

[image]

It worked with the genymotion emulator, and I have no reason to doubt it would stop working now, this is as far as testing with actual mobile devices went - I am not going further dragging a plethora of handsets into the office from all over until I know why. Ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a same problem two solutions :

- you need hard write on you viewport your height and your width.
- or you need dynamics rewrite view port with JavaScript. You need use DPI device * screen.height and than width.

Comment: yeah, in the end I physically hard coded the width and height into a database I don't think you can get dpi in javasctipt